# Submit button not giving required result

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My submit button is not displaying output when i am pressing it but when i do a backspace it is giving me the output on the screen.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S6eTr.png)

Comment: Please don't post images of code. You can copy paste the code here

Comment: FYI - take a look at [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) for many reasons why it's important to include properly-formatted text instead of images of text. Beyond that, you really need to provide more info than code + "it doesn't work" - provide as much detail as possible to help others help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Post code instead of posting images

According to the image that you have provided, inside saveTask you are pushing the obj to the taskList and then passing it to the state updating function.
Arrays are of reference type and since here you are not passing a new array, react will figure out that the array hasn't changed (although you have appended the obj) and hence it won't trigger a re-render.

So change your code to this,

```
const saveTask = (taskObj) => {
      setTaskList(prevList => {
           prevList.push(taskObj) 
           return [...prevList]      
      })
}
```

Comment: Now its giving the output two times, i am new to this technology thats why facing a lot of issues.     const saveTask = (taskObj) => {
    setTaskList(prevList => {
         prevList.push(taskObj) 
         return [...prevList]      
    })
}
   const handleSave = () =>{
    let taskObj = {}
    taskObj["Description"] = description
    saveTask(taskObj)
   }

Comment: Remove the Strict Mode component from index.js and it'll give you a single output

Comment: What can i do now to store this data on local storage? I know i have to use JSON.stringify function for that

Comment: localStorage.setItem("keyName", "valueName");

Comment: yes i am doing the same, should i add this line above return[..prevList]? Really confused

Comment: yeah obviously everything after return won't run